# How do I prevent the css style of the copied text from getting copied as well

Tags: html, css

I have a span tag in my content with some text in it and it has some basic inline style.

When I copy the text and paste it in Sparrow or Gmail the css applied to the span tag gets copied as well.

Is there a way I can prevent this from happening.

I am using Windows 7 but this happens on the Mac as well

The line that I am copying has the following HTML

```
<span style="display:inline-block;background:#f5f5f5; padding:2px;"> My text goes here </span>
```

Comment: just Ctrl + Shift + V to paste

Comment: In chrome there is a workaround if you use CTRL + SHIFT + V instead of CTRL + V , but I need a cross browser solution

Comment: First copy it to notepad and then copy the text from notepad and paste it wherever you need

Comment: Well I have been pasting into notepad, but is there no html attribute or css way to prevent the styling from being copied ?

Comment: You could view the email without HTML and then just copy the text you want. GMAIL: Open the desired message. -> Click on the down arrow next to Reply or More Options. -> Now click Show original.

Comment: apologies, i feel that this question would be better asked on superuser.. no pressure just saying.

Answer (score 0):

Paste in Gmail, then Cut from Gmail, 
Paste in Notepad, then Cut from Notepad,
finally, Paste in Gmail.

Comment: Thanks @marlenunez but Ive tried this already was wondering if there is an attribute or some thing I could add to the span tag to prevent the style from being copied as well

Comment: I see. In that case, if you're willing to edit the span tag, then you might as well remove the style attribute altogether. Or, you mean to add something to it when generating the HTML code?

Comment: The issue I am facing is in all websites even ones which I cannot edit the html. If you copy a line of text and paste it the style gets added as well